# Pass a script variable from HTML to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I tried to find a solution but nothing is working for me, or too complicated.

I'm trying to send a variable from a script in my HTML to my php file.

Here my HTML script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DetectAndServe() {
        urlp=[];u=location.search.replace("?","").split("&").forEach(function(d){e=d.split("=");urlp[e[0]]=e[1];})
        var redirectlink = "https://www.mywebsite.com/redirect_app?utm_medium=" + urlp.utm_medium + "&utm_source=" + urlp.utm_source + "&utm_campaign=" + urlp.utm_campaign;
    }   
</script>
```

What's the easiest way to use the redirectlink variable in my PHP file

Comment: AJAX is the only option here.

Comment: Ok thanks, can you be more specific, how to use it in my case, I'm beginner

Comment: Please do some research into using AJAX, and then come back here when you have a specific question -- SO is not a drive-thru code generation service.

Comment: You can also make a form to post you're URL into the php file

Comment: do you need to invoke that link so you can capture `urlp.utm_medium`, `urlp.utm_source` and `urlp.utm_campaign` as `$_GET['utm_medium']`, `$_GET['utm_source']` and `$_GET['utm_campaign']` respectively?

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do it with form adding this in a form I already have in my page  
<input id="redirectlink" name="redirectlink" style="display: none"></input>

With this at the end of my script
document.getElementById("redirectlink").innerHTML = redirectlink.toString();

But when I try to access it in my PHP with $redirectlink=$_POST["redirectlink"];
I don't have anything

Comment: @coderodour no I don't need, I will also try like this

Comment: _Here my HTML script..._ Ehh.. this is javascript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to create a form to send the result of your function into the PHP file.

Example of form with JavaScript:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" id="redirectlink" name="redirectlink">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
<script>
function DetectAndServe() {
    urlp=[];u=location.search.replace("?","").split("&").forEach(function(d){e=d.split("=");urlp[e[0]]=e[1];})
    var redirectlink = "https://www.mywebsite.com/redirect_app?utm_medium=" + urlp.utm_medium + "&utm_source=" + urlp.utm_source + "&utm_campaign=" + urlp.utm_campaign;
    return redirectlink;
}  
document.getElementById('redirectlink').value = DetectAndServe();
</script>
```

In your PHP you retreive with:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['redirectlink'])){
    $link = $_POST['redirectlink'];
    echo $link;
}
```

Comment: `DetectAndServe` is not returning anything.

Comment: Yep, just fixed it

Comment: Thank you so much it's working well, I just have an other issue now I'm unable to reset the form with document.frm.reset(); I have the error "document.frm.reset is not a function", I maybe need to post an other question

Comment: You need to use it like this `document.getElementById("idform").reset();`

Answer (score 0):

In your html file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/myfile.php?variable1=value1&variable2=value2';
</script>
```

In your php file 
you can get the value pass to the url via `$_GET` request

```
echo $_GET['variable1'] // print value1
echo $_GET['variable2'] // print value2
```